# Draw points inside or outside of a polygon (TiKZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hello I have this plot and I would like to draw two points at coordinates `(3,1)` and `(4,4)` in colour red.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Low capacity scenario (Scenary=2)},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xlabel={arrival/15min},
    ylabel={departure/15min},
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=8,
    enlargelimits=false
   ]
   \addplot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (4,0)
    (4,1)
    (3,3)
    (0,4)
    (0,0)
   }; 
   \legend{maximum capacity}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

How can I do that? Only plotting two circular red dots inside the already done plot? Thanks for helping. I couldn't find any similar graph in the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add two plots at your desired coordinates by:

```
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(3,1)};
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(4,4)};
```

Or by adding another plot with an option `draw=none` as:

```
\addplot[draw=none,red,mark=*] coordinates {
   (3,1)
   (4,4)
   };
```

in the same `axis`, which gives you the following figure:

[image]

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Low capacity scenario (Scenary=2)},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xlabel={arrival/15min},
    ylabel={departure/15min},
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=8,
    enlargelimits=false
   ]
   \addplot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (4,0)
    (4,1)
    (3,3)
    (0,4)
    (0,0)
   }; 
   \legend{maximum capacity}
   \addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(3,1)};
   \addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(4,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! It worked perfectly right. I couldn't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 3):

While adding them through a `\addplot` command is one option, you can always draw those circles yourself. When you have the `pgfplots` version 1.12 installed and with the line `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` in the preamble, this would suffice:

```
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
.
.
.
\fill[red] (3,1) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (4,4) circle (2pt);
```

If you have older versions than 1.12, do this:

```
\fill[red] (axis cs: 3,1) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (axis cs: 4,4) circle (2pt);
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Low capacity scenario (Scenary=2)},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xlabel={arrival/15min},
    ylabel={departure/15min},
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=8,
    enlargelimits=false
   ]
   \addplot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (4,0)
    (4,1)
    (3,3)
    (0,4)
    (0,0)
   };
   \legend{maximum capacity}
   \fill[red] (3,1) circle (2pt);
   \fill[red] (4,4) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]